# MongoDB - find query to check if few fields exists, combined with AND on a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some documents in a collection:

```
{
    name : 'Peter'
    city : 'New York'
    dogs_owned : 2,
    cats_owned : 1,
}
{
    name : 'Amir'
    city : 'Chicago'
}
{
    name : 'James'
    city : 'Chicago'
    dogs_owned : 3
}
{  
    name : 'Leilani'
    city : 'Chicago'
    cats_owned : 3,
}
```

I want to write a find query that returns documents where one of multiple fields exists and another condition is met.

Specifically I want the documents that have the fields cats_owned OR dogs_owned,  AND city = chicago.

So the query would return the documents of James and Leilani in the above example.  Using the node driver for mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$or](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) & [$exists](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "your_db_or_cluster_url";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    const dbo = db.db("your_db_name");
    dbo.collection("your_collection_name").find({
        city: "Chicago",
        $or: [{ dogs_owned: { $exists: true } },
        { cats_owned: { $exists: true } }]}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

**Test here:** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2FuKXY_NZZP)

**Note:** Do not forget to maintain proper indexes.

Comment: This works for me in mongoplaygrounds, but when I put it in my code I get  MongoServerError: $or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue with this code, probably your inputs to query, Can u print & share your query&inputs here!